# How can i make uniqueness in a sql table with using columns?

Tags: sql, oracle, unique

in my table there is no unique column , but i need to make uniqueness with using columns , adding a new column is worst option , i need to do this something like concat two or more columns how can i do that ?

i need to make uniqeness in my sql table with using two or more columns , adding a new columns is worst option , i need a solution which is concat two or more columns something like that how can i do that ?

Comment: Making Unique index using concatenation of two or more columns will create Unique index but the point is, only one time NULL is allowed for each column. So if any column will be getting multiple nulls then creating Unique Index using those column is not good. Just a note.

Comment: You have tagged Oracle and SQL Server. They are different RDBMS and use different syntaxes; which one are you using?

Comment: i am using oracle database

Answer (score 1):

**Oracle**
There is a way to check for "uniqueness" if you compare distinct values of different field combinations with total number of rows.  In below example the score 0 (zero) means uniqueness:

```sql
WITH
  tbl AS
      (
          Select 1 "COL_1", 'AXC' "COL_2", 'khgh jklj' "COL_3" From Dual Union All
          Select 3 "COL_1", 'AXC' "COL_2", 'khgh jklj' "COL_3" From Dual Union All
          Select 3 "COL_1", 'DEF' "COL_2", 'khgh jklj' "COL_3" From Dual Union All
          Select 1 "COL_1", 'DEF' "COL_2", 'xxxx yyyy' "COL_3" From Dual  
      )
Select 
    Count(*) "TOTAL",
    Count(*) - Count(DISTINCT COL_1) "COL_1_SCORE",
    Count(*) - Count(DISTINCT COL_2) "COL_2_SCORE",
    Count(*) - Count(DISTINCT COL_3) "COL_3_SCORE",
    Count(*) - Count(DISTINCT COL_1 || COL_2) "COL_1-2_SCORE",
    Count(*) - Count(DISTINCT COL_1 || COL_3) "COL_1-3_SCORE",
    Count(*) - Count(DISTINCT COL_2 || COL_3) "COL_2-3_SCORE",
    Count(*) - Count(DISTINCT COL_1 || COL_2 || COL_3) "COL_1-2-3_SCORE"
From
    tbl

/*  R e s u l t:
     TOTAL COL_1_SCORE COL_2_SCORE COL_3_SCORE COL_1-2_SCORE COL_1-3_SCORE COL_2-3_SCORE COL_1-2-3_SCORE
---------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ------------- ------------- ------------- ---------------
         4           2           2           2             0             1             1               0
*/
```

Comment: that looks good but i just need to add that i already have a table , and i can nnot make uniqueness with using only one column , i need to be sure that what is the way that i can make uniqueness with using already existing columns like concat or something like this

Comment: @burak That is exactly why I posted this -to help you find the uniqueness. Do the same with your table and your column combinations. We don't know what they are or how many are there...

Comment: @burak There is CONCAT of two or three columns in the answer. Score zero is for COL_1 || COL_2 and for COL_1 || COL_2 || COL_3.

Answer (score 1):

You can combine a handful of columns into a unique row id with the following SQL code.
I have done this when making data sets for machine learning in BigQuery.

```sql
select distinct
cast(to_hex(SHA1(concat(column1, column2, column3, column4))) as string) as observation_id
from table
```

Of course you need to check beforehand, that the combination of these columns produces unique rows.

Comment: If you look at my solution below I too suggest concatenation but not with columns rather with random number, part of SYSTIMESTAMP and a sequence

Answer (score 0):

One option is to create a **unique index** on set of columns you want to enforce uniqueness on.

For example:

```
create unique index ui1_test on test (id, name, address);
```

Doing so, users won't be able to insert new rows (or update existing ones) to a combination (of these columns) that already exists in the table as Oracle will raise an error.

Comment: thanks for comment , but first i need to be sure that there is uniqueness

Comment: OK; then make sure there is uniqueness. How can we, as a community, help you with that? We don't have your table nor data.

Comment: How so "first"? 
When you create a unique index, it the condition is not met the creation fails. Here is your "first".

Answer (score 0):

I just implemented the following to make customer_id a unique column by combining a random number, part of a SYSTIMESTAMP and a sequence NUMBER. To make it difficult to decipher and shorter in length I ran in through a function. I also store the origin (seed) that was used to create the unique column.

As for the first_name and last_name I use so it makes sense in the example as there are names associated with customers.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE mf_names IS
  FUNCTION random_first_name(
    gender        IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL,
    percentage_mf IN NUMBER   DEFAULT 50
  ) RETURN VARCHAR2;

  FUNCTION random_last_name RETURN VARCHAR2;
END;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY mf_names IS
  first_names_male SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST := SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST(
    'Tom', 'Andrew', 'Paul', 'Peter', 'Keith', 'Mark', 'Solomon', 'Joseph', 'John', 'Melvin', 'Harry', 'Barry', 'Larry', 'Gary', 'Jeffrey', 'karl'
  );
  first_names_female SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST := SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST(
    'Alice', 'Anna', 'Barbara', 'Carol', 'Debra', 'Madison', 'Faith', 'Cheryl', 'Beth', 'Kathy', 'Jill', 'Grayce', 'Lynn', 'Roz', 'Deena', 'Laura', 'Sophia'
  );
  last_names SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST := SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST(
       'Cooper',  'Dimeo', 'Spatafore', 'Jones', 'Coralnick', 'Torchiano',  'Fazio', 'Behrens', 'Lebowitz','Stern', 'Malden', 'Kramer','Stein', 'Tessio', 'Weinreb', 'Dillon',  'Rucker',  'Silverberg', 'Aarron',  'Kern',  'Saladino', 'Rice', 'Sanford', 'Orr', 'Roth' 
  );
  
  FUNCTION random_first_name(
    gender        IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL,
    percentage_mf IN NUMBER   DEFAULT 50
  ) RETURN VARCHAR2
  IS
  BEGIN
    IF UPPER(gender) LIKE 'M%' THEN
      RETURN first_names_male(FLOOR(DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(1, first_names_male.COUNT + 1)));
    ELSIF UPPER(gender) LIKE 'F%' THEN
      RETURN first_names_female(FLOOR(DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(1, first_names_female.COUNT + 1)));
    ELSIF DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(0, 100) < percentage_mf THEN
      RETURN random_first_name('M');
    ELSE
      RETURN random_first_name('F');
    END IF;
  END;

  FUNCTION random_last_name RETURN VARCHAR2
  IS
  BEGIN
    RETURN last_names(FLOOR(DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(1, last_names.COUNT + 1)));
  END;
END;
/

CREATE TABLE CUSTOMERS (
 customer_id VARCHAR2 (20),
 seed NUMBER,
 first_name VARCHAR2 (20),
 last_name VARCHAR2 (20));


create sequence customer_seq start with 1000000 minvalue 1000000 maxvalue 9999999 cycle;

create or replace function base34(p_num number) return varchar2 is
      l_dig varchar2(34) := 'AB0CD1EF2GH3JK4LM5NP6QR7ST8UV9WXYZ';
      l_num number := p_num;
      l_str varchar2(38);
    begin
     loop
        l_str := substr(l_dig,mod(l_num,34)+1,1) || l_str ;
        l_num := trunc(l_num/34);
       exit when l_num = 0;
     end loop;
    return l_str;
end;
/

create or replace function dec34(p_str varchar2) return number is
     l_dig varchar2(34) := 'AB0CD1EF2GH3JK4LM5NP6QR7ST8UV9WXYZ';
      l_num number := 0;
    begin
     for i in 1 .. length(p_str) loop
        l_num := l_num * 34 + instr(l_dig,upper(substr(p_str,i,1)))-1;
      end loop;
     return l_num;
   end;
 /

create or replace trigger customer_trg 
    before update on customers for each row
    begin
            if ( updating('customer_id') )
            then
   raise_application_error(-20000,'Cant Update customer_id');
            end if;
            if ( updating('seed') )
           then
raise_application_error(-20001,'Cant Update seed');
            end if;
 end;
/

DECLARE 
   seed NUMBER;
begin
      for i in 1 .. 10 loop
          seed := (to_number(trunc(dbms_random.value(1000,9999))||       to_char(systimestamp,'FFSS')||customer_seq.nextval));

         INSERT into customers(
             customer_id,
             seed, 
             first_name, 
             last_name
          )  VALUES (
          base34(seed), 
          seed,
          mf_names.random_first_name(),
          mf_names.random_last_name()
        );
       end loop;
    end;
/

SELECT * from  customers 

CUSTOMER_ID    SEED    FIRST_NAME    LAST_NAME
BJGEYVDR5HSBEL8    3754328637000441000120    Cheryl    Stern
B8FPDSMR0WQSTNZ    4886346472000441000121    Roz    Dillon
00KGDZARBUZTCB6    5711346658000441000122    Solomon    Kern
KBMP0WU4VQ76T5    1058346784000441000123    Grayce    Lebowitz
0EXWKL06SC2E3R6    6080346899000441000124    karl    Jones
BM9XSDNX7CWNNZC    4128347038000441000125    Alice    Sanford
01SKXFTE18JTT5M    5981347154000441000126    Cheryl    Saladino
B53A6Y19CF7B54F    4164347334000441000127    John    Stein
B3XMHNKT9LDLSDA    3726347470000441000128    Joseph    Lebowitz
B7FT0265MYGJUTP    4643347602000441000129    Debra    Rice


 select to_char(seed) from customers where rownum = 1
    union all
    select base34(seed) from customers where rownum = 1
    union all
    select to_char(dec34(base34(seed))) from customers where rownum = 1;

TO_CHAR(SEED)
3754328637000441000120
BJGEYVDR5HSBEL8
3754328637000441000120


select base34(seed),
dump(base34(seed)) from customers where rownum = 1

BASE34(SEED)    DUMP(BASE34(SEED))
BJGEYVDR5HSBEL8    Typ=1 Len=15: 66,74,71,69,89,86,68,82,53,72,83,66,69,76,56
```